# VB.NET treeview error add second child nodes

Tags: vb.net, treeview, parent-child

I have problem about showing tree with treeview in VB.net

Here the code with looping

```
    While Not mROC.EOF
        tmpStr = ""
        For i = 0 To UBound(sColumns) Step 3
            If sColumns(2 + i) = "" Then
                tmpStr = tmpStr & mROC(sColumns(i)).Value
                tmpStr = tmpStr & "   "
            Else
                tmpStr = tmpStr & Format(mROC(sColumns(i)).Value, sColumns(2 + i))
                tmpStr = tmpStr & "   "
            End If
        Next

        If mROC("parentCode").Value = "" Then
            srcTv.Nodes.Add(mROC("code").Value & "A", tmpStr)
        Else
            Dim TNode() As TreeNode = srcTv.Nodes.Find(mROC("parentCode").Value & "A", True)
            TNode(0).Nodes.Add(mROC("code").Value & "A", tmpStr)
        End If
        mROC.MoveNext()
    End While
```

srcTv is treeview

mROC is database looping with select command

tmpStr just combine field code and description from database, ex: "CT00001  Ari "

Here is database

```
code    |description   |parentCode
-----------------------------------
CT00001 |Ari           |KMD
CT00002 |Angga         |KMD
CT00003 |Bagus         |CT00001
KMD     |Parent_A      |
OLH     |Parent_B      |
```

The result i want is

```
KMD Parent_A
    -CT00001 Ari
        -CT00003 Bagus
    -CT00002 Angga
OLH Parent_B
```

My code is working fine when the parent just has 1 child,but error when load for second child (CT00003 Bagus).

Please help me for this project and GBU for reader and answering my question. ^_^

Comment: Flattening a tree-structure into a dbase table is very problematic.  Either the table needs to be carefully sorted, so you only ever encounter parent nodes before child nodes, or you have to search for the parent nodes yourself.  You are doing neither.

Comment: That was my first guess to, but he states that everything works well untill he reaches a level 2 node, only reason why that would happen is if he tries to assign a key that is already used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm,

You seem to get duplicate Keys.
Try this:

```
        If mROC("parentCode").Value = "" Then
            srcTv.Nodes.Add(mROC("code").Value & "A", tmpStr)
        Else
            Dim TNode() As TreeNode = srcTv.Nodes.Find(mROC("parentCode").Value & "A", True)
            Dim sKey As String = mROC("code").Value
            If srcTv.Nodes.Find(sKey & "A", True) Is Nothing Then
                sKey &= "A"
            Else
                sKey &= "B"
            End If
            TNode(0).Nodes.Add(sKey, tmpStr)
        End If**
```